# How to extract double value from a string in java

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Below is total string i have but i want to extract 31.0, could someone help on this.

String Inseam = {"value":"30inch"-33inch" Shorts","key":"31.0"}

I need 31.0 as an output to use the value some where

Comment: the curly brack at start of string shows its an array of Strings? and I gues 'inseam' is typo for inStream?

Answer (score 0):

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.jayway.jsonpath</groupId>
    <artifactId>json-path</artifactId>
    <version>2.4.0</version>
</dependency>
```

```
JsonPath.parse(Inseam).read("$.key");
```

Full example:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String inseam = "{\"value\":\"30inch\", \"key\":\"31.0\"}";
        String keyValue = JsonPath.parse(inseam).read("$.key");
        System.out.println(keyValue);
    }
```

Output:

```
31.0
```